# Error while submitting a form including two fields for dates and using date_diff() in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

hi everyone im submitting a form having two fields "time_in" and "time_out"

and im trying to get the difference between the two dates using date_diff()
i made sure that time_in in the database is in DATE formant and time_out DATE format as well both are not strings

and i get this error : Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: date_diff0: Argument #1 (SbaseObject) must be of type DateTimelnterface, string given in C:\ampp\htdocs\aicAdmin\scripts\backend-script.php:97Stack trace: #0
C:ilxampp\htdocs\aicAdmin\scripts\backend-script.php(97):date_diff(°2023-05-19,2023-05-23#1(main]throwninC:\xampp\htdocs\aicAdmin\scripts\backend-script.phponline97

while my code is

```
    <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Time in" name="time_in" value="<?php echo $time_in; ?>">
            </div>
        </div> 

    <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="date"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Time out" name="time_out" value="<?php echo $time_in; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
```

and in the backend code

```
if(empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name']=='current_job'){
   extract($_POST);
  if(!empty($jobnumber)){
   

      $data= [
        'jobnumber'=>$jobnumber,
       'revison' =>$revison,
       'groupp'=>$groupp,
       'checker'=>$checker,
       'releasedate'=> $releasedate,
       'quote_number'=> $quote_number,
       'building_number'=>$building_number,
       'task'=>$task,
       'designer_ca'=>$designer_ca,
       'designer_name'=>$designer_name,
       'time_in'=>$time_in,
       'time_schedule'=>$time_schedule,
       'time_out'=>$time_out,
       'spent_time'=>date_diff($time_out,$time_in),   
       'quote_weight'=>$quote_weight,
       'job_weight'=>$job_weight,
       'cycle_time'=>$cycle_time,
       'chk_time'=>$chk_time,
       'wd'=>$wd,
       'remarks'=>$remarks

       
     ];
  

    $tableName=$_GET['name']; 

    if(!empty($data) && !empty($tableName)){
       $insertData=insert_data($data,$tableName);
       if($insertData){
         echo "<span class='success'>Current Job Was saved sucessfully</span>";
       }else{
         echo "<span class='fail'>Error!.. check your query</span>";
       }
    }

}else{
  echo "<span class='fail'>Current Job field is empty</span>";
}

}
```

i didn't copy the whole form code just a snippet
how can i fix this please ??

i double checked that in the database time_in and time_out are stored as DATE format and i excpect everything to work normally

Answer (score 1):

Their is not really enough info here to truly answer this quesiton.

But from the error the issue appears to be your time_in and time_out are not DateTime object.

You must first push them through the `DateTime:CreateFromFormat`.
This will make them DateTime objects.
date_diff will then get you a DateInterval object that still cannot be stored cleanly in a database.

Consider instead taking advantage of unix epoch timestamps.

```
$datetime_in = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i a', $form_time_in); 
$datetime_out = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i a', $form_time_out);
$seconds_elapsed = $datetime_out->format('U') - $datetime_in->format('U');
```

Note: 'h:i a' expects format "1:30 am" see other options [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php).

Comment: im still beginner tbh tell me what more do you want me to explain ?

Comment: @AnyName35425 For starters the html is not helpful in this scenario. Consider simplifying the code to just PHP and just the data you are looking at. This may also help you debug the code yourself. Write a simple PHP script that starts with the moment you retrieve the data and prints the desired results to the screen. I suspect this exercise will show you how to fix the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think a little more context may be needed to fully answer your question but, I'm going to assume you're experiencing a similar problem to what I did last year with this same function.

To test this out, I'd recommend trying to echo your date variables. If it works then they are the wrong data type as for the diff method to work the parameters needs to be  Objects not Strings.

Here are two ways you can get the data type your need.

```
$start_date= new DateTimeImmutable('2009-10-11');
$end_date= new DateTimeImmutable('2009-10-13');
$interval = $origin->diff($target);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Alternatively you can do it this way.

```
$time_out= new DateTime('today');
$time_in= new DateTime('tomorrow');
$interval = date_diff($time_out, $time_in);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Also, I recommend documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: im still beginner tbh tell me what more do you want me to explain ?

Comment: @AnyName35425 No big deal, I think the thing most people would be looking for is something like the lifecycle of the two date variables you are trying to compare leading up to the error.  Meaning all the steps of what happens to the variables `($time_out and $time_in )` from declaration to the point the problem occurs. **TLDR;** More code makes helping you debug easier. Hopefully this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is also helpful